# page title, parent tilte and grand parent title

Tags: pages, title, hierarchical

I am using a page hierarchy and I want to show the title of the parents and grand parents page (if there is any).

The structure is something like

Startpage

Startpage > Second page

Startpage > Second page > Third page

Startpage > Second page > Third page > Fourth page

The title should be something like
On the Fourth page: "Fourth page - Third page - Second page - Startpage"
On the Third page: "Third page - Second page - Startpage"

The solution I have found isn't that good:

```
<title><?php

if(is_page()){

$parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
$parent_title = get_the_title($parent);
$grandparent = $parent->post_parent;
$grandparent_title = get_the_title($grandparent);
    if ($parent) {
        if ($grandparent) {
            echo wp_title('') . " - " . $parent_title . " - " . $grandparent_title . " - ";
        }
        else {
            echo wp_title('') . " - " . $parent_title . " - ";  
        }
    }

    else {
        echo wp_title('') . " - ";
    }
}?>  Startpage</title>
```

On the Second page level the title for that page gets double... "Second page - Second page - Start page"

Anyone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

possibly build on [`get_ancestors()`;](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors)

example:

```
if( is_page() ) :
    echo $post->post_title;
    if( $ancs = get_ancestors($post->ID,'page') ) {
        foreach( $ancs as $anc ) {
        echo ' -> ' . get_page( $anc )->post_title;
        }
    }   
endif;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution. It uses the [get_ancestors()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors) function, which returns an array of the current page's ancestors from lowest to highest in hierarchy.

Since I didn't really get in which order you wanted to display it (lowest to highest or highest to lowest), I set a $reverse param (default:false) to change the order.

```
<?php 

function print_page_parents($reverse = false){
  global $post;

  //create array of pages (i.e. current, parent, grandparent)
  $page = array($post->ID);
  $page_ancestors = get_ancestors($post->ID, 'page');
  $pages = array_merge($page, $page_ancestors);

  if($reverse) {
    //reverse array (i.e. grandparent, parent, current)
    $pages = array_reverse($pages);
  }

  for($i=0; $i<count($pages); $i++) {
    $output.= get_the_title($pages[$i]);
    if($i != count($pages) - 1){
      $output.= " &raquo; ";
    }
  }
    echo $output;
}

//print lowest to highest
print_page_parents();

//print highest to lowest
print_page_parents($reverse = true);

?>
```

I hope it helps!

Vq.